# how to pass query param in Retrofit GET API?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

My **buid.gradle** is like that.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Generating **Api Client**

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static RestApiMethods getRestApiMethods() {
        return createRetrofit().create(RestApiMethods.class);
    }

    private static Retrofit createRetrofit() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = getBuilder();
            httpClient.protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    @NonNull
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder getBuilder() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG)
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout((long)60 * 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout((long)60 * 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout((long)60 * 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // add logging as last interceptor
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        return httpClient;
    }


}
```

**calling like**

```
@GET("URL")
Call<ResponseClass> getUser(@Path("id") int id);
```

on calling API, getting an error of annotation. 
How can I make Url like URL/id?=1.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 @GET("URL")
Call<ResponseClass> getUser(@Query("id") int id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Query` annotation to add parameter to you API call

```
@GET("URL")
Call<ResponseClass> getUser(@Query("id") int id);
```

It'll generate an url like this: `URL?id=your_id`

Answer (score 0):

In Your interface update `getUser()` method and add `@Query` instead `@Path`

```
@GET("URL")
Call<ResponseClass> getUser(@Query("id") int id);
```

If it is `POST` request and you want to send `FormUrlEncoded` values use this code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("URL")
Call<ResponseClass> getUser(@Field("id") int id);
```